# Defining colors in a custom LaTeX class

Tags: documentclass-writing

i am trying to create my first custom latex class based on KOMA and i can't figure out how to define/use custom colors in that context.

My goal is to have a colorized title. The problem is that when i use a custom defined color, the title (or any other text for that matter) becomes invisible (but it is there!).

I have been searching for the solution to this problem for hours without success and i have no idea of what might be wrong here.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
% File: 'myclass.cls'    
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myclass}        
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{40,40,40}
\LoadClass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{
    \begin{center}
        \Large
        \color{mycolor}
        \@title   % <-- invisible
    \end{center}
    \pagebreak
}
\endinput

% File: textfile.tex
\documentclass{myclass}    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{mytitle}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RGB (which accepts parameters between 0 and 255) instead of rgb (which requires parameters between 0 and 1). See [p.10, xcolor manual, v2.11](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/xcolor/xcolor.pdf#page=10).